# Set value into an input text in a row of a table using jquery / yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

This is development of my question in : [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359512/adding-new-row-in-dynamic-form-yii2-in-new-row-js-is-not-work).
This is the screenchot of my app : 
[image: Screenshoot]

Please see, I have a dropdown list in first column (item),
when selected, I will update the third column like this

```
$.get("/index.php?r=kasir%2Ftransaction%2Fget-price-item&amp;id=" +$(this).val(), function(data){
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".harga-jual").val(data.price.harga)
    });
```

My goal is, I want to set value the harga's column on row itself.
So, in select option at first row selected, harga's updated just in first column, 
next in second so on...

How can I selected this on jquery ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try without encoding.. /index.php?r=kasir/transaction/get-price-item&id= , check if the ajax call is successful, check the data from ajax is as expected..

Comment: Yes, the ajax is working,  I have debug it with console.log(data). I dont kow to select the html element that I want to as aabove.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with `$(this)` in `$.get()`. Save the $(this) reference outside of the ajax call and try to use in ajax as code below

```
$("item1").on('change', function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $.get("/index.php?r=kasir%2Ftransaction%2Fget-price-item&amp;id="   +$(this).val(), function(data){
    console.log("harga:"+ $this.closest("tr").find(".harga-jual").length);
    $this.closest("tr").find(".harga-jual").val(data.price.harga)
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for user3498863,

Now code it successfully works like this :
in yii way :

```
 <?=
                                    $form->field($modelTools, "[{$indexTools}]item_id")->label(false)->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(ItemLayanan::find()->all(), 'id', 'nama_item'), ['prompt' => 'Select item',
                                        'class' => 'item_id',
                                        'onchange' => ''
                                        . 'var $this = $(this);'
                                        . 'var $row = $this.closest("tr");'
                                        . '$.post("' . Url::to(['get-price-item', 'id' => '']) . '" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
                                                  $row.find(".harga-jual").val(data.price.harga);
                                           });']
                                    )
                                    ?>
```

Thanks again